# This device cannot find enough free resources that it can use. (Code 12)

Tags: windows-xp, troubleshooting, sound-card, resources

My audio card won't work from this morning.

Problem: This device cannot find enough free resources that it can use. (Code 12)

What can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally this means that more than one device is trying to use the same I/O port. Open device manager and see if there are any exclamation points next to any items. You want to locate the device that is causing the I/O conflict and then disable it.

Did you install any hardware or software recently that may have changed your configuration? If so, you can also try uninstalling the hardware/software or even rolling back to a previous version of Windows using the System Restore tool.

Comment: I didn't change a thing in the last two weeks.
The yellow exclamation mark is right on my Creative SB X-fi audio card.
Now, for a reason, the error changed into "This device cannot start. (Code 10)".
What?

Comment: @iTayb You should add that information into your original question; you can click the *'edit'* button to do so.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue with Windows 10 even, on an older laptop. The wifi and/or usb wasn't working. They take turns to work.

I got around it by disabling and then enabling the hardware that is connected to the problem device via Device Manager.
Click in Device Manager click View -> by Connection to show what root devices are linked to that problem device.

Extra:
I then automated the enable and disable of the device by using DevManView.exe via task scheduler when the computer starts or logs in.
It seems to be some race condition. But either way, turning off and on some of the Intel CH controllers that are the parents of the problem device (wifi in this case), seems to work.

This article helped me get a hint: https://www.reddit.com/r/windows/comments/10g694/please_help_me_this_device_cannot_find_enough/
My problem was also with an ATI based laptop:

> This is a bug on some systems, and can be rather annoying to fix. I've
> seen it several times. I'm guessing you have an Intel processor, with
> the integrated Intel graphics. Under device manager you should have
> the menu for "system devices". Expand this. I'm then going to guess
> that one of the first few devices says ATI (maybe AMD) USB filter
> driver. If it does, uninstall this. When it is done, reboot the
> system.
>
> When you reboot, the system will install all of the chipset
> drivers again. Guess what! It's back again! Sometimes it changes from
> AMD to ATI 3GIO Pci express filter driver. Repeat the process of
> uninstalling and rebooting. This could take 3 or 4 tries to get it to
> finally go away. Then it should be gone forever, unless you reinstall
> the driver.